# How to deny direct access to a folder using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is all about images. So I want to find a way to prevent direct access to images folder using (I guess) .htaccess.
From what I've read one way is to move the images folder out of the web-root and then add an .htaccess file with the following code:

```
deny from all
```

So here are my questions:

- Will I have any problems if I don't move the folder outside the web-root? Because I will have to make a lot of changes to the code in all pages. What's the logic behind moving the images folder outside the web-root?
- Is there any other safe way to do this? I am worrying that If add .htaccess that will deny access to all images then I won't be able to share my pages and use the images in them.

**UPDATE:**

What about if I use the following code that will prevent hotlinking of my images but will allow it to specific websites.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yordomain2.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yordomain3.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://page-to-redirect [NC,R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move your images folder outside your web root, you don't need that `.htaccess`. Directories outside your web root can't be accessed from outside.

So you can do both, but not together.
Anyways your images can not be used on your site as long they are not accessible. To show an image on your site it has to be 'loadable'.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your input. So that means that I can't actually deny my images no matter which I choose as they won't be 'loadable'? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Technically showing an image on your page is the same as downloading that image.

Answer (score 1):

1) Redirect all requests to the image folder to the index.php script using .htaccess:

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

2) In your index.php do some logic to determine if the image should be served.

```
// Do some checking...
$safe = true; // determine if the image should be served
if($safe){
    header("content-type: image/png"); // or gif or jpg
    readfile($_GET['q']);
}
```

Comment: Can you please check my updated question :) I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

to prevent reviewing of images folder content.

Another way you can put index file to the images folder.

If you publish some images on the pages it's impossible to restrict download of them.

Comment: With HTML5 you could draw the images to a canvas, which would make it pretty dern difficult for the average user to download your images.

Comment: I agree, but printscreen can grab everything, and it's very popular now, especially for tablet computer users. Cropping isn't difficult task too. Watermark is still better protection, i think.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use that for the same problem:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
# Only from this website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$ - [NC,F]

# To prevent access to crawlers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?:google|tineye) [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [NC,F]
```

It does not really blocks access to images, but access from other websites pages.