# htaccess redirect url to different folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have all the photos of my website located in `/var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/sitename/uploads/`, and my site is located in `/var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/httpdocs`, sitename and httpdocs are located on the same level. When a user looks for some photos I want to look into `/sitename/uploads` and not `/httpdocs/uploads`, my htaccess file is located in `httpdocs/.htaccess`. 
I tryied using `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/sitename/uploads/(.*)/$ uploads/$1 [QSA]
```

but nothing changed, I've been trying different RewriteRules for a while now and I can't figure out one that should work.
Any Ideas? thanks

Comment: Apache cannot load content from outside `DocumentRoot` and here `/sitename/` is outside `DocumentRoot`

Comment: mod_write works on urls, not filesystem paths.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to redirect your image requests to a script then have the script serve the files. See my answer here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136239/how-to-deny-direct-access-to-a-folder-using-htaccess/34136491#34136491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem adding a RewriteRule to my htaccess like this
`RewriteRule ^/uploads(.*) /var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/sitename/uploads/`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this directive in my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myweb.conf`:

```
Alias /upload/ /var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/sitename/uploads/
<Location /upload>
Require all granted
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```

Then any web request for `http://myweb/upload/file.ext` would send the file `/var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/sitename/uploads/file.ext` to the browser.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, unfortunately I'm using plesk(not my decision) and I can't find a way to access teh file you mention, I have only access to `/var/www/vhosts/myvps.ovh.net/` subfolders, any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I have root on all my computers, so I can edit anything in /etc and therefore did not solve such problems. If it would not work from `.htaccess`, I am afraid I cannot help you with this :(